# Call function every day in fixed time in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I call function from a Django server every day in the same time?

Comment: There is a 100% painless way of doing this. A cron job.

Comment: Or even less painful and more [django-integrated](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: `do you have a specific time in your visitors?` @ofersto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django allows you to write custom management commands (similar to runserver or shell).

[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) is a tutorial.

You can simply make your own management command and then run that command as a cron job.

[here](http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/) and [here](http://crontab.guru/) are some tutorials to setup a cron job.